# I'm having trouble showing that a subset of a matrix ring is a subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\Lambda = \Big\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ b & a & c \\ c& b & a\end{pmatrix} : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_{3} \Big\} \subset M_{3}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$

I'm supposed to show that $\Lambda$ is a commutative subring of $M_{3}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$, but when showing that if $A,B \in \Lambda \rightarrow AB \in \Lambda$, I got a matrix which does not lie in $\Lambda$. Did I mess up, or is there something wrong in the problem?

What I did:

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ b & a & c \\ c& b & a\end{pmatrix}, \: A'= \begin{pmatrix}a' & b' & c' \\ b' & a' & c' \\ c' & b' & a'\end{pmatrix}$.

I don't want to write out all the computations I did for the product $AA'$, but I will give you the elements $AA'_{1,2} = ab' + ba' + cb'$ and $AA'_{2,1} = ba' + ab' + cc'$. These should be equal, so since they are not obviously equal, must I further analyse every possible value $c,b',c'$ can take to see if the product is in $\Lambda$?

Comment: I wonder what your counterexample is. I and other people can check your 'counterexample' if you give it in your question.

Comment: Right, will do.

Comment: I am pretty sure the $c$ at the middle right spot is a $b$.

Comment: @MooS: No, this is also not a subring then. Take $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=0$ in your $A$, then $A^2$ has diagonal $(1,0,1)$ which is not of type $(a,a,a)$.

Comment: Ok, I must admit, I have not done any calculations. It just seemed natural to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ b & a & c \\ c& b & a\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}d & e & f \\ e & d & f \\ f& e & d\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}ad+be+cf & ae+bd+ce & af+bf+cd \\ bd+ae+cf & be+ad+ce & bf+af+cd \\ cd+be+af& ce+bd+ae & cf+bf+ad\end{pmatrix}$$

doesn't seem to be true... but to be sure let's pick a base of it

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$

Now if the products of these lie in $\Lambda$ we're ok. The first one is the identity matrix, so nothing to check here.
We have to do
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^2  = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1& 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \not\in \Lambda$$
(no need to check the other three)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll skip this problem then :)

Comment: @Auclair Or perhaps look it up again; something must have been confused.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a problem from an old exam, and it is stated exactly as I did here. I'm sure it just was a mistake by the professor.

Comment: Well, we cannot verify this, of course. It would be interesting to know which set it should have been. Almost nothing of this kind works. There must be another misunderstanding, perhaps.